# Display ONLY IP addresses of currently logged users

Tags: linux, bash, networking

I want to get a list of the currently logged users and their respective IP addresses.
 
I tried the following command line:

```
w -s
```

However, the TTY, IDLE and WHAT columns are also displayed. I don't want those columns to be displayed as I plan to use only the needed information as an input to a script. Is there any way to filter those columns out? Any way of getting a list with just the users and their IPs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
w -hs|awk '{printf "%s\t%s\n",$1,$3}'
```

Comment: It does. Thank you very much! Wow, it seems that I definitely need to learn more about awk. I feel so embarrassed :P

Comment: It's a pretty handy tool for minor data processing tasks, I highly recommend adding it to your repertoire.